# Серверный java демон, несколько нюансов

Tags: веб-программирование, java, сервер, хостинг

Для начала сразу оговорюсь - с `web`-технологиями и администрированием знаком весьма поверхностно, так что не осуждайте за глупость вопроса.

Суть вот в чем: требуется создать сайт, который взаимодействует с БД. На этой же площадке требуется расположить программу-демона на `java`, которая взаимодействует с этой БД и с различными API'шками сторонних сайтов, причем делает это в режиме 24/7 (мониторит изменения БД постоянно + еще несколько пермаментных действий).

Так вот, проясните пожалуйста такие нюансы, как:

1. Выбор языка для программы. Критично ли это, или `java` вполне подойдет? (нагрузки не сверхбольшие, но многопоточность весьма вероятна)
2. На какой площадке размещать данный проект? Подойдет ли тут простой хостинг, или потребуется `VPS` (вирт. сервер)?
3. Если все-таки потребуется отдельный сервер, то какое программное обеспечение будет необходимо для функционирования ?

Comment: 24/7 позабавило... Если бы было 24/5 или 24/6 тут надо было думать, а когда 24/7 это проще простого :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многопоточность в вашем случае не просто вероятна, а необходима для адекватной реализации. Поэтому java - самый надежный выбор. Для обслуживания сайта начните с Tomcat - масса примеров и готовых решений. Для выбора хостинга погуглите "tomcat hosting".

Comment: Только вот модель потоков в Java и **серьезный (24/7) сервер** вещи трудносовместимые.

Обычно, почти все описания многопоточности в книжках это нечто достаточно идеальное, некоторые, на первый взгляд неважные, ньюансы практической жизни не рассматриваются.

--

IMHO при не  слишком большой нагрузке (к сожалению, реально проверяется только практической эксплуатацией) лучше делать многопрцессную (и желательно без shared memory), а не многопоточную структуру. (но Java тут не очень подходит).

В ней по сравнению даже с native threads намного проще обрабатываются "сбойные" ситуации.

Comment: Ну это кто как умеет. В java-потоке я поставлю перехват всех исключений и буду знать, что поток свалился, а как следить за отдельным процессом, не представляю.

А то что якобы "модель потоков в Java и серьезный (24/7) сервер вещи трудносовместимые" - бездоказательная инсинуация.

Comment: Tomcat для таких вещей мало подходит. Я бы не рискнул делать ставку на него. В конце-то концов - Tomcat всего лишь референсная реализация JSP/Servlet контейнера некими потугами на продакшн. Тут надо брать (если жить с Java) что-то из разряда WebLogic, WebSphere или JBoss.

Comment: @rfq, а принудительно, но корректно для остальной системы, завершать "зависший" поток в Java умеете? Насколько я помню, потоки в Java обязаны завершаться сами (скажем, реагируя на "прерывание"), но ведь всякие ошибки в программах бывают.

Так что, Вы правы, кто-то умеет делать реальные вещи, а кто-то не совсем  представляет, какие "подводные камни" там есть. 

Вообще, программирование надежных серверных приложений штука очень непростая.

Comment: @avp корректно для системы завершить поток, в котором обнаружилась программная ошибка? Не вижу смысла. Ошибка могла уже распространиться за пределы потока, лучше рестартовать весь процесс. 
А еще лучше, не выпускать в продакшн полуработающие программы, чем потом виртуозно перезапускать подвисшие подпроцессы и при этом гордиться тем, что "мы умеем делать реальные вещи".

Comment: @rfq, не смею спорить с рассуждениями типа - 

"*лучше быть здоровым и богатым, ...*"

Answer (score 0):

На такие вопросы даже не знаю как правильно ответить... =)

1. можно и джава, можно и пхп и шарп, и рельсы, на чем умеешь на том и пиши :)
2. если джава - надо сервер, который будет ее поддерживать (их мало, таких провайдеров)
3. сервер (ПО) в зависимости от выбранных технологий

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,

3. Имелось ввиду ПО для запуска того самого java демона. Хотя бы в каком направлении копать?

Comment: JVM, JRE, JDK